# Get category title by slug

Tags: categories, slug, getsegment

I'm setting my categories by matching the third segment to a category slug. How do I get the category title?

```
{% set catSlug = craft.request.getSegment(3) %}
{% set category = craft.categories.slug(catSlug) %}
```

{{ category.slug }} returns the slug, but {{ category.title }} returns nothing.

Comment: If `{{ category.slug }}` is giving you the slug, it sounds like you’ve got is actually working. Not sure why `{{ category.title }}` would not be working though. What does `{{ dump(category) }}` give you? (you’ll need to have [dev mode](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/config-settings#devMode) enabled to use that `dump()` function.)

Comment: Hmm looks right to me? Could be the category is disabled?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You need to add `.first()` when setting the category. As far as I can tell, if you don't have `.first()` only `{{ category.slug }}` will work.

First get the slug:

```twig
{% set catSlug = craft.request.getSegment(3) %}
```

This will give you the [CategoryModel](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/templating/categorymodel) object for catSlug:

```twig
{% set category = craft.categories.slug(catSlug).first() %}
```

You can now access whatever you want from the category, like the title:

```twig
{{ category.title }}
```

Comment: You can’t pass in a string (`catSlug`) to `craft.categories()` – that `.slug(` is required to tell Craft that what you’re passing in is the slug, as opposed to an ID, etc.

Comment: @Brandon Required as in it won't work without it or as in you really should use it? This code worked for me, maybe my test wasn't in a clean enough environment.

Comment: Required as in there’s no way it will work that way, and if it appeared to work, you probably just got lucky with the desired category happening to be the first one in the group.

Comment: @Brandon You got it, I did get lucky. :) I edited my answer, the lack of `.first()` is what was giving @brunam problems.

Comment: Ah good catch! That explains why `category.slug` was working but `category.title` wasn’t – it was just returning the parameter value, rather than an actual category’s slug.